# I'm always getting a single route no matter what origin and destination I set

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, google-directions-api

I'm getting in my directions as explained in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). My link looks like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=lat,lng&destination=lat,lng&mode=walking&key=KEY
```

Which works perfectly fine. However, it doesn't matter what origin or destination I set, I'm always getting a JSON file with a singe route. See the below screenshot:

https://ibb.co/x7K4B1c

Is this correct? Is there any way I can get multiples routes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the official documentation explains it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Directions API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

> alternatives — If set to true, specifies that the Directions service
>   may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that
>   providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the
>   server. This is only available for requests without intermediate
>   waypoints.

You need to set the alternatives to get one or more routes from origin to destination.

In your case you may be try like this and see the output

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=lat,lng&destination=lat,lng&mode=walking&key=KEY&alternatives=true
```

Comment: Didn't found that in the docs. Thanks for making it clear.